# Yii2 jsPosition POS_HEAD not working with Twig

Tags: twig, yii2, assetbundle

I am use Yii2 advanced with Twig integration. I need include js and css files to head block and use AssetBundle for this.

If I use POS_BEGIN or POS_END it's work. Js and css load to page in current position. But if I set position as POS_HEAD render ignore this and no load files to page.

Please help. What am I doing wrong?

**My AssetBundle**

```
namespace frontend\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class YandexAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        '/css/map.css'
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/map.js',
        'js/test.js'
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
    public $jsOptions = [ 'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD ];
}
```

**And connect in Twig template**

```
{{ use('frontend/assets/YandexAsset')}}
{{ register_yandex_asset() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html :

> Asset dependencies are mainly specified through the
>   yii\web\AssetBundle::$depends property. In the AppAsset example, the
>   asset bundle depends on two other asset bundles: yii\web\YiiAsset and
>   yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset, which means the CSS and JavaScript files
>   in AppAsset will be included after those files in the two dependent
>   bundles.

both assets
'yii\web\YiiAsset',
'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset', 
are included at end of rendered page and your asset cannot be placed before them because they are depended of them.

if you want to include js file in POS_HEAD you can use `registerJsFile()` in your view or layout file

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJsFile()-detail

Comment: I remove all depends in Asset and now files don't include to the page